# Failed to build httptools, how to fix it

Tags: python, pip, fastapi

when I try to install FAST API (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial /).
im using Python 3.10.2, Pycharm
I get the following error with httptools.
I have already installed build tools which is given by the link.
and updated setuptools, wheel and pip using

> `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

but I still get this error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: httptools<br />
  Building wheel for httptools (setup.py) ... error<br />
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error<br />

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.<br />
  │ exit code: 1<br />
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]<br />
      running bdist_wheel<br />
      running build<br />
      running build_py<br />
      creating build<br />
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10<br />
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\httptools<br />
      copying httptools\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\httptools<br />
      copying httptools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\httptools<br />
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\httptools\parser<br />
      copying httptools\parser\errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\httptools\parser<br />
      copying httptools\parser\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\httptools\parser<br />
      running egg_info<br />
      writing httptools.egg-info\PKG-INFO<br />
      writing dependency_links to httptools.egg-info\dependency_links.txt<br />
      writing requirements to httptools.egg-info\requires.txt<br />
      writing top-level names to httptools.egg-info\top_level.txt<br />
      reading manifest file 'httptools.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'<br />
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'<br />
      adding license file 'LICENSE'<br />
      writing manifest file 'httptools.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'<br />
      copying httptools\parser\parser.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\httptools\parser<br />
      copying httptools\parser\url_parser.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\httptools\parser<br />
      running build_ext<br />
      building 'httptools.parser.parser' extension<br />
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/<br />
      [end of output]<br />
<br />
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.<br />
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for httptools<br />
  Running setup.py clean for httptools<br />
Failed to build httptools<br />
Installing collected packages: httptools, certifi, ujson, python-multipart, orjson, jinja2, itsdangerous, dnspython, charset-normalizer, requests, email_validator, fastapi
  Running setup.py install for httptools ... error<br />
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error<br />
<br />
  × Running setup.py install for httptools did not run successfully.<br />
  │ exit code: 1<br />
  ╰─> [27 lines of output]<br />
      running install<br />
      c:\users\ghali\pycharmprojects\tat\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and ot
her standards-based tools.<br />
        warnings.warn(<br />
      running build<br />
      running build_py<br />
      creating build<br />
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10<br />
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\httptools<br />
      copying httptools\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\httptools<br />
      copying httptools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\httptools<br />
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\httptools\parser<br />
      copying httptools\parser\errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\httptools\parser<br />
      copying httptools\parser\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\httptools\parser<br />
      running egg_info<br />
      writing httptools.egg-info\PKG-INFO<br />
      writing dependency_links to httptools.egg-info\dependency_links.txt<br />
      writing requirements to httptools.egg-info\requires.txt<br />
      writing top-level names to httptools.egg-info\top_level.txt<br />
      reading manifest file 'httptools.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'<br />
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'<br />
      adding license file 'LICENSE'<br />
      writing manifest file 'httptools.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'<br />
      copying httptools\parser\parser.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\httptools\parser<br />
      copying httptools\parser\url_parser.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\httptools\parser<br />
      running build_ext<br />
      building 'httptools.parser.parser' extension<br />
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/<br />
      [end of output]<br />
<br />
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.<br />
error: legacy-install-failure<br />
<br />
× Encountered error while trying to install package.<br />
╰─> httptools<br />
<br />
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip<br />.
hint: See above for output from the failure.<br />
```

Comment: The error message says: "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/". Have you tried doing what it suggests?

Comment: of course, but it didn't help. I have installed the Visual Studio 2019 Build Tools.

Comment: Which version of httptools? httptools 0.4.0 has prebuilt whls for 3.10 (some earlier versions will only have 3.9, etc.): https://pypi.org/project/httptools/#files

Comment: unfortunatly, dont really know.

Comment: The version number will be specified in your requirements.txt file - or it will be present in the pip log when the package is attempted to be installed (slightly higher up than where the log in your question starts).

Comment: After installing the Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 build tools also some other error poped up. Updating the version number of `httptools` version from `0.4.0` to `0.5.0` in requirements file fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I couldn't solve this problem using python 3.10 
The only thing that helped me was **rolling back to python 3.8.6** (it will probably work in python 3.9 as well)
As far as I understand, the problem is the incompatibility of the current version of httptools and python 3.10
If anyone finds a solution, be sure to write.
I will wait.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to try upgrading the version of httptools. I was able to build it for 3.10.9

```
Python 3.10.9 (main, Jan 11 2023, 09:18:20) [Clang 14.0.6 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import httptools
>>> httptools.__version__
'0.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same problem by adding the following libraries:

`sudo apt install python3.10-distutils`

`sudo apt install python3.10-dev`

Python version ***3.10.13***

Answer (score 0):

belated updated, this was/is caused by httptools putting windows support at a lower priority and not releasing windows wheels as timely as linux ones.  There have been many cases across the years of lack of windows wheels causeing this issue for various python versions.  HttpTools will eventually release a windows wheel and it's fixed, until the next python version comes out and they once again don't bother to provide a windows wheel until enough people complain ;)

As of now up to 3.10 at least should have a windows httptools wheel and install without issue for most people.  If you're stuck behind a firewall like me you will have to request an update to your pip mirror or downgrade your python.  Trying to install visual C++ to build the wheel manually never seems to work.

given how frequently it's come up I wouldn't be surprised if at some point a new python also lacks a httptools wheel and a new generation of folks find this question and if so you will just have to downgrade or wait for them to put out a windows wheel.